# Sql percentage calculation and grouping

Tags: sql

I have a table containing the name of a shop, the sale date  and the  items sold:

```
Shop    |    Date   | Item

Shop1   |   xxxxx   | A
Shop1   |   xxxxx   | B
Shop1   |   xxxxx   | B
Shop1   |   xxxxx   | A
Shop1   |   xxxxx   | A
```

So they sold 3 items 'A' and 2 Items 'B'

So that, item A (3 sold) is 60% of the total (5 items sold)  and Item B is 40%

So I wish to obtain something like this:

```
Shop1   |   A    |  3    |  60%
Shop1   |   B    |  2    |  40%
```

It should be obtained by:

```
Select Shop, item, count(item),  count(item) *100 / (select count(item)  from table) +  '%'
from table
group by Shop, item;
```

My problem is that the tables does not contain only one shop but others shops too: shop1, shop2 and so on.

So i'd like to obtain a result like this:

```
Shop1   |   A    |  3    |  60%
Shop1   |   B    |  2    |  40%
Shop2   |   A    |  8    |  80%
Shop2   |   B    |  2    |  20%
shop3   |   A    |  1    |  100%
shop4……
```

Any help?

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 1):

In SQLServer2005+

```
SELECT shop, item,
       COUNT(*) * 100. / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY shop) AS Perc
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY shop, item
ORDER BY shop, item
```

Demo [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9607e/1)

Comment: @Aesse Welcome to stackoverflow...You need to read these posts: How does accepting an answer work?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I creates a table with 20000 random values and tested 3 above answers and discoverd that the Fedorenko's answer is faster than benty23.
 In query plan 0.250533 was for Fedorenko and 0.354073 for benty23.
So using window functions for this question is the best solution.

Comment: Yes, they work very well and they are what I was exactly looking for.   thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
Select i.Shop, 
       i.item, 
       count(i.item), (count(i.item) * 100 / t.cnt) 
  from table1 i
  join (select shop, count(shop) as cnt from table1 group by shop) t
    on i.shop = t.shop
 group by i.Shop, i.item, t.cnt
```

see also this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f87a98/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT( A.SHOP ) ,A.ITEM ,COUNT(A.ITEM) ITEMS ,CAST(COUNT(A.item) * 100 / B.COUNT_OF_SHOP AS VARCHAR(10)) + '%'
FROM    percentage A JOIN 
( SELECT   shop ,COUNT(shop) AS COUNT_OF_SHOP FROM percentage GROUP BY shop ) B ON A.shop = B.shop
GROUP BY A.Shop ,B.shop ,A.item ,B.COUNT_OF_SHOP
```